# Prevent comment conflicts in strings.resx (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, versioning, conflict

Suppose an international team of developers, using various flavors of `Visual Studio 2010` (understand: in different languages), and working on a versioned project.

Every time one of them makes a modification on the `Strings.resx`, Visual Studio happily **generates the file with localized comments**. Every time two or more of them do so at the same time, some pretty annoying **conflicts appear**, which not only are time consuming, but also are completely pointless. Developers get angry and all.

How can this be prevented? Is there a way to tell Visual Studio not to regenerate those comments, or to drop them altogether?

Comment: I presume it isn't possible to have each developer lock the resx file before editing and then unlock when finished?  (of course, I'm not sure how often individuals have to work on the Strings.resx file at the same time)

Comment: This sounds difficult to apply, as it requires changes to be quick enough. As soon as some task involves that file and take, say, a day or two, you cannot reasonably lock it as many people work with it.

Comment: Ok- then how about a script/macro that each developer runs on the file prior to commiting that strips ALL comments from the file.  I mean, VS can re-generate them if you really need them.  Or you could re-factor the Strings.resx into several smaller files to reduce the number of conflicts.  Just throwing out thoughts- HTH.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Actually since those comments are easy to identify, I am currently trying on my spare time to hack a diff/patch based script to revert them. But I'm rusty when it comes to these tools and there seem to be encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent Visual Studio generating localized comments in the `.Designer.cs` file which backs every `.resx` file. And I'd certainly like to know.

Until someone finds out, you'll have to setup Visual Studio in English (or whatever language is shared by most of your team) everytime you want to change the resources.

You can do that in `Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings` (you need to restart VS).

When programming, I don't mind setting up everything in english, rather than in my native tongue, because exceptions and error messages are almost always easier to google when they are in english.

HTH

Comment: Well, I am actually using the English version. Problem is: most of the other developers are not, and for various reasons (including: they would mind), I cannot require them to do so. On my side, using the language they use would make VS unusable for me.

Comment: Then just edit the resource files manually. It is pretty much straightforward.